# How to unpack different values depending on number of variables to unpack into

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I'm scratching my head over how to conditionally unpack variables from a class depending on the number of variables you are unpacking into e.g. I get a different set of variables unpacked depending on the number I set on the left hand side of the assignment.

For example, lets consider a class that has both x, y, z and latitude & longitude positions:

```py
class LatLonOrXYZ:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, lat, lon):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        self.lat, self.lon = lat, lon

    def __iter__(self):
        # not sure...
        return iter([self.x, self.y, self.z, self.lat, self.lon])
```

Now I want to achieve something like the following:

```py
pos = LatLonOrXYZ(x=0, y=1, z=2, lat=3, lon=4)

x, y, z = *pos  # 0, 1, 2
lat, lon = *pos  # 3, 4
```

Are there any deep python magics that could accomplish this sort of thing or am I better off just writing a couple of methods that feel so unnecessary?

As ever, any help, insights or advice would be greatly received :-)

Comment: No deep magic that I'm aware of, and even if there was, I'd suggest not using it.  It's hard to tell the intention with that paradigm.  I think it's better just be explicit and use a method. :-)

Comment: What is the role of `pos` in your snippet? You don't seem to be using it at all after assigning to it.

Comment: Just a side note, but you want to be using your instance, not your class. That is: `x, y, z = *pos` rather than `x, y, z = *LatLonOrXYZ`.

Comment: Is there some reason not evident in the example that you wish to use an iterable, rather than something like: `x, y, z = pos.x, pos.y, pos.z # 0, 1, 2` and `lat, lon = pos.lat, pos.lon # 3, 4`? I'm not sure I understand why an iterable would be called for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely doable, but may not be the best application, in your example, of an iterable.

Basically, create a `list` from your iterable, as in `list([*pos])`, then slice it as desired like `list([*pos])[0:3]`.

Here's your example code with this in operation:

```
class LatLonOrXYZ:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, lat, lon):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        self.lat, self.lon = lat, lon

    def __iter__(self):
        # not sure...
        return iter([self.x, self.y, self.z, self.lat, self.lon])

pos = LatLonOrXYZ(x=0, y=1, z=2, lat=3, lon=4)

x, y, z = list([*pos])[0:3]
lat, lon = list([*pos])[3:5]

print(x, y, z)
print(lat, lon)
```

Output:

```
0 1 2
3 4
```

As a side note, in your example code, you are calling your actual class object rather than your `pos` instance. It's important to understand the difference.

Rather than:

```
pos = LatLonOrXYZ(x=0, y=1, z=2, lat=3, lon=4)

x, y, z = *LatLonOrXYZ  # 0, 1, 2
lat, lon = *LatLonOrXYZ  # 3, 4
```

What you want to do is:

```
pos = LatLonOrXYZ(x=0, y=1, z=2, lat=3, lon=4)

x, y, z = *pos  # 0, 1, 2
lat, lon = *pos  # 3, 4
```

The first line creates an object based on the class definition that is an `instance`, or an object using the structure and behavior of the `class` that you'll be using as a position in your code.

Consider the following:

```
pos_1 = LatLonOrXYZ(x=0, y=1, z=2, lat=3, lon=4)
pos_2 = LatLonOrXYZ(x=4, y=3, z=2, lat=1, lon=0)
```

These are two different objects with their own characteristics, both structured as the `LatLonOrXYZ` `class` has laid out. Separate buildings based on the same blueprint.

This is a really basic description meant to just point out the gist of the thing. You can read more about python `classes`, here in technical form:

[Python.org Classes Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Or, as an example of the decent explainers, but by far not the only excellent, accessible discussion regarding this stuff for which you should google lots :) , here:

[OOP in Python - at Real Python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)